# Declare many constants ? Swift

Tags: swift, constants

I’m using a custom .xib view which is reused in a stackView depending on how many entries an array contains:

Not actual, just example array:

> let array = [“first” , “second”, “third”]

```
for i in 1...array.count
{
let view = MyCustomView()
view.label.text = array[i-1]
stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
}
```

What’s the best way to change the label.text later on for each different view through a function?

I could declare the view at top as:

```
let view1 = MyCustomView() 
let view2 = MyCustomView()
let view3 = MyCustomView()
...
```

But then I would have to declare a lot of views I might not use just to make sure there is enough for the count, and to be able to change the label.

Is there a quick method or dictionary style declare of view[1] etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your views directly from the stack view since they are kept in the order you added them, that way you don't need to have some additional properties for them or an array.

```
stackView.arrangedSubviews
```

One way to set the labels would be to iterate over the `arrangedSubviews` array

```
for (index, view) in stackView.arrangedSubviews.enumerated() {
    if let myView = view as? MyCustomView {
        myView.label.text = array[index]
    }
}
```

or individually if you know the index

```
if let view = stackView.arrangedSubviews[i] as? MyCustomView {
    view.label.text = array[i]
}
```

In both cases you would need some validation to verify your index value isn't out of bounds.

Comment: Thank you, that’s exactly what I need it. Also for future reference, what did I write wrong in my question for it to be rated down? So I can improve in the future.

Comment: And now i can't post anymore questions after this question? I thought this forum suppose to help..

Comment: I am not a moderator here so I am not sure why you are complaining to me.

Comment: Sorry, thought you were, Im just confused why my question was voted down to start with as I followed all the rules in writing it and presented it well, and you answered it well. And following the downscale on it I'm banned from writing questions. The moderators aren't the best here

Answer (score 0):

You could create an empty array of type `[MyCustomView]`. Append new `MyCustomView` into this array as you're creating them.

Declare as:

```
let array = ["first", "second", "third"]
var myCustomViews = [MyCustomView]()
```

And append new `MyCustomView` as you create them:

```
for i in 0..<array.count {
    let view = MyCustomView()
    myCustomViews.append(view)
    view.label.text = array[i]
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
}
```

Later on, you can access them like:

```
myCustomViews[1].text = "New text"
```